# Build Tetris game with a command-line interface using java

Tags: java, command-line, architecture

I have a java school project (software architecture) : I must code a Tetris game with a command-line interface and multiplayers in networks. My questions are:

1. Is there good tutorials about the command line interface with java to start with since I have not too much time and my searchs led almost to nothing useful.
2. I have already coded a tetris game using swing, can I use the code of some functionalities in my new project?
3. The teacher said it's easier to make a command line interface than to use JFrame but he didn't explain more so why it's easier?

Thank you for your answers ! :)

Comment: Command line is easier than using GUI because you get the same functionality without needing the move boxes around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TheNewBoston has very good tutorials about java.
2. Yes you can use some code, for example your written classes. But maybe you must import a package.
3. Command line is easier than Jframe, because you get the same functionality , without shapes move around.